# Adding a custom marker in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know how to add a custom marker to my map in android. The custom marker is in my drawable folder and is named car.png . Given below is the code for google map API v2 in android.At present

I am getting the standard google map marker

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;     
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapp);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String lats = extras.getString("LATITUDE");
        String longts = extras.getString("LONGITUDE");
        String speeds = extras.getString("SPEED");


        double latt= Double.parseDouble(lats);
        double longt=Double.parseDouble(longts);

        final LatLng Location=new LatLng(latt,longt); 
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1))
                .getMap();      

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("The Speed Of The Vehicle Is: " + speeds + "kmph"));

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


        CameraUpdate cam=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Location,15);
        mMap.animateCamera(cam);

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This page has information on how to use a custom image as the marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker

Example from the above source:

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

You can use `fromResource`, `fromFile`, `fromBitmap`, and `fromAsset` with the `BitmapDescriptorFactory` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html